# Is it possible to find the equation of straight line if the point on the line and direction cosines of line perpendicular to it are given?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Is it possible to find the equation of straight line if the position vector of the point on the line and direction cosines of line a perpenducular to it are given? I tried to solve this problem using dot product but I ended up getting an equation of plane rather than that of a line.

Comment: You are in $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: What do you mean by "direction cosines of line a perpendicular to it"? More generally, can you please be more explicit, both in your question and in your attempt?

Comment: The direction cosines of that line that is perpendicular to your line are just the three components of the unit direction vector of that line.  However, there is an infinite of lines that are perpendicular to this "perpendicular line", so your line, that one you're interested in, has no known direction, other than that it belongs to the plane whose normal vector is the given "perpendicular" line.  In other words, you have a whole family of such lines, not just a single one.

Comment: @ofcourse Is it possible to uniquely identify "my line" among those family of lines if a point on "my line" is given?

Comment: No.  It's not possible.  The given point specifies which **plane** this family of lines belong to, but it does not uniquely determine the direction of the line.  To uniquely identify your line you need more information.  For example, if you specify a **second** line to which your line is perpendicular to, then you would have enough information to uniquely determine your line.

Comment: The direction cosines form a unit vector. For any given unit vector and a point in space, there is a unique plane passing through the point, and perpendicular to the unit vector (that is, every displacement vector between any two points in the plane will be perpendicular to the unit vector). Thus just one point and a perpendicular vector defines a plane, not a line. To identify your line, you need either a second point on the line (in which case the vector is unneeded), or a second vector (not parallel to the first) which is also perpendicular to your line.